# Launch a Python GUI from a C program running with user root

Tags: python, c, root, xorg

I made a C program that in some moment calls its python GUI.

When running both C and python on my desktop with sudo, it works because sudo is executing the C program as my user.

But, I made a systemd unit to launch the C code on boot, so it is being executed by user root, and then I can't make it show the Python GUI on my desktop because I get `WARNING **: Could not open X display`.

The C code is watching a binary with inotify and does some work when the binary is opened and opens the Python GUI with a simple `system` call.

The C code has to be executed with root privileges, but the python GUI can be launched as regular user and when it needs it, maybe using polkit to get it. It just have to write some things in a xml file localted in /var/lib.

Any idea how I could do this?

Answer (score 0):

The reason it works when you run it the first way is that the `DISPLAY` environment variable is already set before you start the C program, and it will be inherited by subprocesses.

If you're launching the C program on bootup, the `DISPLAY` variable (probably) won't be set, so you'll need to set it before spawning the subprocess, with something like...

```
#include <stdlib.h>

setenv("DISPLAY", something, 1);
// Now launch the Python script
```

The tricky bit is what to put in for `something`. It needs to be whatever you get when you do `echo $DISPLAY` from a regular X11 session, assuming the C program runs on the same system as your X11 session.

You'll either have to hardcode a value which works, or find some way to pass the correct value to the C program.

---

**Update**

Regarding permissions issues - one simple fix would be to put `xhost +root` in `~/.xsession`, assuming you trust root.

Otherwise you can force the Python script to run as your UID instead. You can either do the proper fork-exec thing, and call [`setuid(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/setuid) in the child process before calling `exec()`, or you could call [`os.setuid()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.setuid) at the top of your Python script.

Comment: The display can be hardcoded to :0 but it doesn't work if I don't do `xhost +` before, and I can't execute that command from the C code because it is running as root right?

Comment: If you're running the command as root, you should be able to tell it to use your X authorization as well. Before your `system()` call to launch the app, set the `XAUTHORITY` environment variable to "/pathto/user/homedir/.Xauthority". This should suffice instead of using the `xhost` command.

Comment: I tried a mix of what you guys said. I've created an user with ID 627, and gave it permission with  xhost +SI:localuser:username`, then on the python code I set `os.setuid(627)` on top of the code, so when I write print(os.getuid()) I get the correct 627. Still the same message appears. The Edelson idea has the problem that I don't know which user is going to see the Python GUI.

Comment: @user712533 TBH, I'm not particularly familiar with the X11 permissions system, but even if you *can* get it working, it seems a bit hacky to have a daemon process, running as root, spawn a GUI directed at some arbitrary X11 session. What should it do if there are no users logged in, or what if you want the GUI to be visible to multiple users? A more flexible approach would be to have the 'interested' user(s) run the X11 program themselves, and have it do IPC with the daemon process.